# Force Image to Top of Page

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to move an image to the top of the page at: Link removed, see below.

Edit: The link above has since been deleted. You can see examples of this at: http://bixproduce.wpengine.com/bix-word/

I want this image to remain full width and sit at the top of the page, with the log-in inputs displaying over the image. This is functional on: http://bixproduce.wpengine.com/

But I just can't make it work with images in a post. I have tried many combinations of overflow, clear, position, etc, but nothing works.

The html looks like this: 
    (edit) I guess I can't put the html on here.

My CSS currently looks like this:

```
.single .entry-thumb {clear: left;overflow: hidden;top: 0 !important;}
.single .entry-thumb img {float: left;}
```

I had to use clear and overflow to force the entry-thumb div to be the same height as the image.

I have tried using 'position:absolute;' on the entry-thumb div, but that shrinks the image somehow and it no longer fills the entire width.

If I manually set a fixed height for both the image and the div, then position absolute works, but the entry-wrap div moves to the top of the screen and seems to ignore the fact that the image is there. A fixed height for the image is not ideal as everything else is responsive.

I have tried so many sources for a fix and tested out numerous possibilities. I just can't make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jared

Comment: You should use that image as `background` not as image in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried wmeade's solution. It did work, but leads to some undesirable styling further down the page.

Nenad Vracar solution is also not exactly feasible as this is a Wordpress site and the image in question is a featured image. You can't add featured images through css, at least not with your style sheet.

I took his recommendation however and did a little research to see if it is possible to force Wordpress to treat the featured image as a background image. I found this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-featured-image-in-div-style-background and used it to modify my post template file. Now it looks great and everything works properly.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing your `top` property a few pixels and adjust the image to where it fits for you. -65px seemed to work when I tested it on the page.

```
.single .entry-thumb {clear: left;overflow: hidden;top: -65px !important;}
```

**Note:** Only use `!important` as a last resort. So test without using `!imporant` and see how everything looks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove image from HTML and add this to your

**CSS**

```
article {
    background: url("http://bixproduce.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/produce-on-wood-hd-01-1184x275.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.entry-wrap {
    padding: 100px 0;
}
```